# Should I create a new context for downstream service call or just simply pass the upstream one?

Tags: go

The process is like this: for each incoming HTTP request, I have an early common handler which will create the context for the request, also there are some other common handlers which will do some pre-processing/parsing operations then put some data in the context for future usages, eventually will call one downstream grpc API.

Now I cannot make my mind on this:

1. I just simply pass the context created by the early common handler to the grpc API call, the concern is the downstream API doesn't need those data previously I put in the context, so I plan to use the `WithValue(parent Context, key, val interface{}) Context` API to set them all to `nil` before making the grpc call;
2. I create a totally new context `outgoingCtx := metadata.NewOutgoingContext(context.Background(), md)`, then upon the early context `ctx.Done()` I called the `Cancel()` on this `outgoingCtx`;

Which option is better, or it doesn't really make any difference, even for very high concurrency case?

Comment: Why are you creating a context in middleware? The http package already creates a context for you for each request.

Comment: @Flimzy so i just simply use the `func (r *Request) Context() context.Context` API to get and use?

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason not to (i.e. you specifically do NOT want your context to be cancelled when the request terminates), yes.

Comment: @Flimzy got it, thank u very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context values are not transported across network boundaries. It's not possible since there is no way to get a list of all values from a context without knowing all the keys.

What *is* transported is the cancelation signal. That is, if the client of your service gives up before an RPC completes, upstream services can stop their work as well. Whether or not that is desired is a case-by-case decision: you may not want to cancel sending email after registration has already completed, but it's usually totaly fine to cancel read-only operations.

Comment: oh, i see, so those values i set in the context actually doesn't matter at all, i can just simply pass the upstream context down to the downstream

Comment: BTW, where i can find any doc to indicate that the context values will NOT be transported across network boundaries, or any example to verify that?

Comment: @Inshi: A more valid question would be "Why would you assume values WOULD be transported?" You won't find documentation for everything not done (i.e. "Where do I find documentation that the context package doesn't clean my toilet?"). You'll only find documentation for things that are supported.